# How can I find out which iOS apps I've purchased were free?

Tags: ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I know that I can see all my purchased apps in the App Store on my iPad but it doesn't give any indication of whether these are free apps or whether I paid for them.

I am in South Africa and have accounts in both the ZA and US stores. Before the ZA store had access to most apps I would buy them from the US store that I had loaded with vouchers. Unfortunately I left my iPad's store connected to the US store and "bought" many free apps there too. Now I keep the ZA store connected and apps purchased from the US store don't update unless I switch stores first.

So I want to uninstall all the free apps I purchased from the US store and re-purchase them from the ZA store, leaving only paid apps purchased from the US store installed. The problem is that once an app has been purchased the app info pages in the store no longer show the cost of the app; so how do I tell free and paid for apps apart? Not having bought the apps by credit card I have no email record of the purchases to refer to.

I rarely use the App Store functionality in iTunes (on Windows) so perhaps that holds some key to this and I will check, but in the meantime I'm hoping someone already has the answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

Not something I've actually tried, but how about sign out on iTunes [store menu], then use the store as an anonymous customer? That might let you see the pricing.

Comment: That's a good idea. I've also thought of using my wife's iPad alongside mine as she won't have many of the apps that I do so I should see the pricing on hers.

Answer (score 1):

A fantastic resource is AppShopper (http://appshopper.com).  It won't give you the cost of the whole list of apps you own all at once, which would be ideal for your situation.  But, if you look up apps in AppShopper, it will give you the complete history of that app's price.  So it will tell you not just whether it is free today, but whether it is sometimes free.  Quite a few apps change their prices frequently, sometimes drastically.  I think they do this partly to capture on the "deal mentality" that makes some people excitedly grab an app if they get a notice that it dropped from $6.99 to free (for instance), and perhaps partly to combine the benefits of increasing their user base (when it's free/cheap) and bringing in revenue (when it's cheap/expensive).  If you notice that some of the apps that you want to keep aren't free today, but have been free several times in the past, they probably will be again!

Comment: A little worrying though that the very first app I searched for was not found.

Comment: Ditto for the second. Doesn't seem as useful as it appears.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange.  I don't recall any apps ever not appearing!

Comment: I tried searching for some of my more obscure apps and they were all there.  Maybe you are filtering in a way that eliminates what you are looking for?  You can set it to only search Mac or iOS apps, or only a particular category.  Try leaving it on "All categories" and make sure you have't selected Mac only.

Comment: I figured out the problems. The app I've always called FlickrStackr is actually called FlickStackr. The lack of vowels made it easy to miss the r that wasn't there. FlickStackr does get found.

The other was more interesting. I grabbed my iPad and reading the app name off the desktop icon, I searched for PhotoMgrPro and got nothing. It was only after not finding it in the app store either that I found the app name is Photo Manager Pro. That one does get found. I never realised that the desktop icon labels might differ from the app's actual name.

Comment: Aha!  Thanks for reporting back, and glad it worked out.  Interesting point about the icon name not matching its full name!

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes:

1. Select "iTunes Store" on the left pane
2. Select "Account" under "Quick Links" on the right side
3. Find "Purchase History" section
4. Select "See All" - free apps will be listed there, as well as paid.